# How to create collection based composite with item template?

Tags: jsf

It is possible to do, only with composites, something like this: ?

```
<customComposite:listRenderer list="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <!-- item template -->
    </h:panelGroup>
</customComposite:listRenderer>
```

listRenderer.xhtml

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="list" type="java.util.List" required="true"/>
        <!-- how to expose "item" via attribute? -->
        <composite:attribute name="var" ???>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.list}" var="item">
            <!-- place there somehow item template -->
        </ui:repeat>
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Not sure, did you try to `<composite:insertChildren/>` into your `<ui:repeat>`?

Comment: @Selaron I'm aware of `<composite:insertChildren/>` but I think this would not work, repeat will output the same `<composite:insertChildren/>` n-times. First I need to figure out how can I expose item model in composite container (if possible) and then how to pass item template that is using exposed item model (if possible).